# Installing Qiime2 on Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, qiime

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to install [Qiime2](https://docs.qiime2.org/2018.8/install/) on Colab? I can't seem to get it to work with !pip install qiime2.

Comment: What is the error that you encounter?

Comment: Collecting qiime2-2018.8
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement qiime2-2018.8 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for qiime2-2018.8

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to create a conda environment in Colab? If you check QIIME2's page (link below), it indicates that first you install conda/miniconda and in conda you create a QIIME2 environment. As far as I know, to run QIIME2 you use the "source activate" command instead of python-based commands

Best!

https://docs.qiime2.org/2018.11/install/native/